# Canvas.redraw doesn't work Java SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, canvas, swt, redraw

I'm working on a SWT app and i can't figured out why canvas.redraw() in MyJoystic class does'nt work!

So, I created 3 Classes: GraphicalComponet, MyJoystic, MyCanvas

1.GraphicalComponet: 3 data members, holding the shell,display and controller for others GraphicalComponet that extetnds this class.

```
    public class GraphicalComponet {

Display display;
Shell shell;
Controller controller;

public GraphicalComponet(Display display, Shell shell, Controller controller) 
{
    this.display = display;
    this.shell = shell;
    this.controller = controller;
}
```

MyJoystic: represents a Joystick that need to be draw on the canvas and update x,y when mouse move.

```
    public class MyJoystic extends GraphicalComponet implements Joystick {

int x,y;
boolean drag =true;

public MyJoystic(GraphicalComponet g, final Canvas canvas) {
    super(g.display, g.shell, g.controller);

    x = canvas.getSize().x;
    y = canvas.getSize().y;

    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {

            int maxX = canvas.getSize().x, mx = maxX/2;
            int maxY = canvas.getSize().y, my = maxY/2;
            int r = Math.min(maxX, maxY)/8;

            e.gc.drawOval(mx-r*2, my-r*2, r*4, r*4);

            e.gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
            e.gc.fillOval(mx-r, my-r, r*2, r*2);

            canvas.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener() {

                @Override
                public void mouseMove(MouseEvent e) {
                        x = e.x;
                        y= e.y;
                        canvas.redraw();
                        doAction(x, y);
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
@Override
public void doAction(double x, double y) {
    System.out.println("JX:"+ x + " ,JY:" + y);
}
```

3)My Canvas: Class that extends Canvas and have some Joystick as data member.

```
    public class MyCanvas extends Canvas {
Joystick joystick;
public MyCanvas(final GraphicalComponet g) {
    super(g.shell, SWT.BORDER);
    this.setLayoutData((new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1)));
    this.setBackground(g.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
}

public Joystick getJoystick() {
    return joystick;
}
public void setJoystick(Joystick joystick) {
    this.joystick = joystick;
}
```

}

Gui for creating all this and read and dispatch loop:

```
    public class GUI implements UI {
GraphicalComponet g;
Controller controller;

public GUI(){
    //display = new Display();
    //shell = new Shell(display);
    g = new GraphicalComponet(new Display(), new Shell(), controller);
    g.shell.setSize(300,300);
    g.shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,false));
    g.shell.setText("Simulator");
    MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas(g);
    MyJoystic joystic = new MyJoystic(g, canvas); 
    canvas.setJoystick(joystic);
    g.shell.open();
}
@Override
public void start()
{
    while(!g.shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if(!g.display.readAndDispatch())
            g.display.sleep();
    }
    g.display.dispose();

}
```

The event listner other lines is all working but it seems that the redraw() not working at all. please help me figured it out. And from one to another, how can i debug swt apps with events? Any thought would help, thanks.

Comment: Try adding `canvas.addMouseMoveListener` outside `canvas.addPaintListener` and consider adding resize listener `canvas.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {});` and call redraw inside resize listener

Comment: i figured out my self, thanks.